# How to get accurate float calculation result?

Tags: floating-point

input are 2 float numbers: num1, num2, calculate num = num1*num2.

Eg:
num1 = 2.09,num2 = 33.85
num = num1 * num2 = 70.74649
num's accurate value is 70.7465

I know we can choose to convert float to int value first by:

```
    int intNum1 = num1 * 100;
    int intNum2 = num2 * 100;
    int intNum = intNum1 * intNum2;
    num = intNum / 10000;
```

Is there another solution to get accurate result? thanks.

Comment: The duplicate is admittedly more about why this does not work as you hope it would. A possible solution (in your case) would be to use a decimal floating point type.

Comment: doit,  Certainly `int intNum = num1 * num2;` should have been `int intNum = intNum1 * intNum2;`.

Comment: `int intNum1 = num1 * 100;` better as `int intNum1 = lroundf(num1 * 100);`.  Form a rounded answer rather than a truncated one.  Leads to `70.746490478515625`, closest `float` to `70.7465`.

Comment: I make a small mistake. Thank chux, I have corrected the sentence:int intNum = intNum1 * intNum2;